# Attempting to add line breaks in Ruby to_s message

Tags: ruby

In Pragmatic Programmer's Ruby book, they're using `to_s` to clean up the output. Their output ends up looking like:

```
Name: UserName, Address: UserAddress, Phone: UserPhone, EMail: UserEmail
```

They don't have any line breaks, and I'm attempting to add them to mine using `\n` within the `to_s` definition:

```
class PersonalInformation
  def initialize (fullname, address, phonenumber, emailaddress)
    @fullname     = fullname
    @address      = address
    @phonenumber  = phonenumber
    @emailaddress = emailaddress
  end
  def to_s
    "Name: #{@fullname}\n, Address: #{@address}\n, Phone: #{@phonenumber}\n, EMail: #{@emailaddress}\n"
  end
end

info1 = PersonalInformation.new('UserName', 'UserAddress', 'UserPhone', 'UserEmail')

p info1
```

but I'm not having any luck getting the output to display the way I want, and it doesn't appear that `to_s` is doing what I expect it to anyway. Mine looks like:

```
#<PersonalInformation:0x00000002d0e600 @fullname="UserName", @address="UserAddress", @phonenumber="UserPhone", @emailaddress="UserEmail">
```

- A) What do I need to do to make `to_s` display the way I expect?
- B) How do I go about getting line breaks into the output message?

Comment: try using `puts` instead of `p`

Comment: You should show how the result of `to_s` differs from what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`p`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-p) calls [`Object#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-inspect) method, not [`to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-to_s).

You need to call [`to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-to_s) explicitly, or use methods that call `to_s`. For example, [`print`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-print), [`puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-puts), [`printf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-printf) with `%s` format.

Answer (score 0):

A) You don't need anything extra. It already displays the way you want.

B) As you did, putting `"\n"` works.